# Why is the database user defined variable returning null?

Tags: database, laravel

In my controller, I define the variable and after, I query my visits table.

```
\DB::statement(\DB::raw('set @row_number := 0'));
$visits = Visit::selectRaw('*, @row_number := @row_number+1 as row')->get();
```

The resulting query shows `row` as `null` for every record? Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

The DB statement was connected to the parent connection and setting the variable there, while the query was running on the child database. I had to updated the code to connect to the correct database first.

```
DB::connection('child_database')->statement(DB::raw('set @row_number := 0'));
```